# Send string over socket and connect to that string

Tags: python, string, sockets, tuples

I have a central server and clients that are connecting to it. A client asks for online sockets to connect to and server answers (for exact type of sockets). To be clearer
server side part of code

client

```
import socket
print 'Dobrodosli! '
socketZaKonekciju = []
def Main():
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5000
c = socket.socket()
c.connect((host, port))
while True:
    k1 = c.recv(2048)
    print "Server: " + str(k1)
    prva = raw_input("-> ")
    c.send(prva)
    k2 = c.recv(2048)
    print "Server: " + str(k2)
    druga = raw_input("-> ")
    c.send(druga)
    k3 = c.recv(2048)
    print "Server:" + str(k3)
    treca = raw_input("->")
    c.send(treca)        
    k4 = c.recv(2048)
    print "Lista online klijenata sa vasom konverzijom \n" + str(k4)
    peta = raw_input("Povezati se na prvog klijenta? \nDa/Ne ")
    c.send(peta)
    k5 = c.recv(2048)
    print str(k5) + "\n"
    k5 # now he shoul connect to k5


    c.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
Main()
```

server

```
import socket
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5000
brKonekcija = 5
buffer = 2048
listaKonv1 = []
listaKonv2 = []
listaKonv3 = []
listaKonv4 = []
def Main():
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
print 'Socket napravljen'
s.bind((host,port)) 
print 'Socket bindovan'
s.listen(brKonekcija) 
print 'Maksimalan broj konekcija: ' + str(brKonekcija) + ' konekcija'
s, addrTCP = s.accept()
print "Nova konekcija" + str(addrTCP)
print "Lista online soketa" + str(addrTCP)
    client = s.getsockname()
    print "Trenutni klijent" + str(client)
    while True:
    s.send("Dobrodosli na server! Za nastavak pritisnite Y")
    k1 = s.recv(2048)
    if k1 == 'Y':
        s.send("Bravo! Pritisnuli ste "+ str(k1) + "\nKoju konverziju pruzate?")
        k2 = int(s.recv(2048))
        if k2 == 1:
            listaKonv1.append(client)
        if k2 == 2:
            listaKonv2.append(client)
        if k2 == 3:
            listaKonv3.append(client)
        if k2 == 4:
            listaKonv4.append(client)
        s.send("Koju konverziju zelite?")
        k3 = int(s.recv(2048))
        if k3 == 1:
            s.send(str(listaKonv1[0]).strip("()"))
        if k3 == 2:
            s.send(str(listaKonv2[0]).strip("()"))
        if k3 == 3:
            s.send(str(listaKonv3[0]).strip("()"))
        if k3 == 4:
            s.send(str(listaKonv4[0]).strip("()"))
        k4 = s.recv(2048)
        if k4 == "Da":
            s.send("\nSrecno!\n")
        if k4 == "Ne":
            s.send("\nPrekidam soket!\n")
            s.close()







        if __name__ == '__main__':
        Main()
```

where server sends first from list for exact type that client asks. So, when client gets this socket it then has to connect to it, but that socket is a string to client. How can i make the string a tupple for a socket connection.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Ideally, you should provide the code you've written as an attempt to solve the problem - the site is intended to help you fix problems or understand issues, not to get you started. The code for connecting the client and server, or the packages you are using, would help as well.

Comment: Added. Also client has to connect to himself to do some stuff (conversion of numbers). Thank you so much!

Comment: What's `connect to a string` supposed to mean? Do you want the client to connect to an IP address?

Comment: remove code that is not relevant to the current problem, [create a minimal complete code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Describe input (its format and an example), what do you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     k5 # now he shoul connect to k5
> ```

This must be wrong, since `k5` contains `Srecno!` or `Prekidam soket!`, not something to which one can connect.

> How can i make the string a tupple for a socket connection.

If a string `str` originates from a conversion of a socket address tuple, the easiest way to convert it back to a tuple is `eval(str)`.